# How can I create a component from a module that's already been imported?

Tags: angular

I have a modal service that's responsible for opening a modal dialog on the fly whose signature is `create<T>(component: Type<T>, params?: Object, module: Type<{}> = AppModule): Observable<ComponentRef<T>>`. The modal service is meant to The problem is that when I import a module that's already been imported, I receive error `Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'MyModule'`. Research shows that this is a common problem when attempting to import things twice.

ModalService -

```
import { Injectable, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, ReflectiveInjector, Injector, Compiler, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
    vcRef: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
               private compiler: Compiler,
               private injector: Injector) {
    }

    registerViewContainerRef(vcRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
        this.vcRef = vcRef;
    }

    create<T>(component: Type<T>, params?: Object, module: Type<{}> = AppModule): Observable<ComponentRef<T>> {
        let componentRef$ = new ReplaySubject();

        this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
            .then(factory => {
                let componentFactory = factory.componentFactories
                    .filter(item => item.componentType === component)[0];
                const childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([], this.injector)
                let componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(componentFactory, 0, childInjector);

                Object.assign(componentRef.instance, params);

                componentRef$.next(componentRef);
                componentRef$.complete();
            });

        return <Observable<ComponentRef<T>>> componentRef$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Usage snippet when trying to open a modal dialog with component `FooComponent` that belongs to `MyModule`.

```
import { MyModule } '../my.module';
this.modalService.create(FooComponent, {}, MyModule)
```

Based on the documentation, the module is required when creating components if it was lazily loaded.

My question is, how can I create a components that belongs to any module, already loaded or not.

Edit! This works if the component I'm dynamically creating does not have any dependencies, which is not likely to happen often.

See Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sGt9XM60BbnjdPCa7QR1?p=preview). Places where I'm having issues with are files `app/core/modal/modal.service.ts` and `app/crisis-center/crisis-list.component.ts` (line 54 - where the modal should open). The error that's showing up is `Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for MyService!`. Not sure why since I'm creating my component from the module where `MyService` is defined as a provider.

Is there perhaps a better approach of accomplishing this?

TL;DR The goal is to create a service (`ModalService` in my case) where any component can be create no matter which module it belongs to. Obviously, it needs to support DI.

Comment: Can you add a plunker that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @yurzui See edit.

Comment: Thanks for your plunker. See my updates https://plnkr.co/edit/L68u5RBnmEQBjR2jJy3P?p=info in `app/core/modal/modal.service.ts` at line 32 and 37

Comment: That worked wonderfully!

Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've gotten this error, restarting my CLI corrects the issue. It's an easy thing to try first before diving into my code.